# creating text files Android IO

Tags: android, adb, text-files

I am trying to make a text file on an android phone and be able to populate it when needed.  I am having problems, obviously, and would see if anyone can take a look at what I have so far.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewLog extends Activity {

    private TextView tv;
    private static final String TAG = "MEDIA";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

        CreateExternalLogFile("I am adding something into the text file!");
    }

private void CreateExternalLogFile(String s){
    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
    tv.append("\nExternal file system root: "+root);
    File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/logs");
    dir.mkdirs(); 
    File file = new File(dir,"log.txt");
    try {
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file,true); //True = Append to file, false = Overwrite
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
        System.out.println(s);
        pw.println(s);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        f.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(TAG, "******* File not found. Did you" +
                        " add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the manifest?");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    tv.append("\nFile written to \n"+file);


}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have used adb to look for the file, but the file is not being created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: This works - Just tested it.

Make sure you have: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /`> in your manifest as well.

```
 package com.example.fileio;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FilioActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView tv;
    private static final String TAG = "MEDIA";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

        CreateExternalLogFile("I am adding something into the text file!");
    }

private void CreateExternalLogFile(String s){
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "filename.txt");
    tv.append("\nExternal file system root: "+ dir);
    try {
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file,false); //True = Append to file, false = Overwrite
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(f);
        p.print(s);
        p.close();
        f.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(TAG, "******* File not found. Did you" +
                        " add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the manifest?");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    tv.append("\nFile written to \n"+file);


}
}
```

Comment: I would like to store the file on the SDcard, which is why I was going for .getExternalStorageDirectory();


when traveling to the filepath it is supposed to be at "/mnt/sdcard/nullwall_logs/log.txt" using adb (looking through the emulator) nothing is in the directory.  Also, the code goes through the try block and does not enter any of the exceptions

Comment: Just edited my post, tested to make sure the code works. Good luck, let me know if you need any more help :)

Comment: great thanks! What was I missing?

You also said make sure you have : in your manifest. Have what? :] Thanks!

Comment: Woops, editted it - should include the permission now :) Don't forget to select my answer ;) Not sure entirely what I changed, I think just the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() as well as the manifest change.

Comment: http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/3718/99413584.jpg

Here is a screen of what I see. Hope this helps! Thank you so much for your help.

All I see is :Make sure you have: in your manifest as well.

Comment: In your AndroidManifest.xml you need <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> to be added above the <application> tag. This will allow your app to have access to your sd card. I wasn't testing with the emulator since I'm not sure how that works - what I normally do is dropbox it to myself and run the .apk on my phone (You can get it out of the /bin folder). Hope that helps :)

Comment: This was just posted, which should help with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013679/how-to-create-virtual-sd-card-in-android