# how to create virtual sd card in android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I want to know how to create a virtual SD card in android. I have one SD card in my emulator, but I want to add one more external (virtual) card to my emulator. Can anybody know how to create one more SD card in my emulator?

Comment: Are you wanting two at one time? (not possible) or another virtual sd card you can swap out in place of the current one?

Comment: thanku.... No one sdcard is full thats wht create another one,how to create virtual sdcard...

Answer (score 3):

Use the mksdcard function to make a new card-

```
mksdcard -l mySdCard 1024M mySdCardFile.img
```

then use emulator options to specify which card to use-

```
emulator -sdcard mySdCardFile.img
```